# rails scope using "AND"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have 2 scopes, the by_group_title does is used in a search box to return group names based off of a user search.  It's working good, however, I'm trying to limit what groups can be returned in the search results.  Specifically I'm trying to exclude any group that has a "membership" of "Restricted", I only want groups returned in the search results when the "membership" is set to "Standard" for the group.

The second scope I have is called by_standard_membership.  This scope will return standard groups but it does not allow searching.  So I'm trying to find a way to combine both scopes so that a user can search for a group title but only the standard groups are shown and the restricted groups do not appear in the search results.

I've been playing around with using an "and" statement to combine them but can't seem to get it working.

```
#scopes
scope :by_group_title, -> (group) { where('title LIKE ?',"%#{group}%" ).order(created_at: :desc) if group.present? }
scope :by_standard_membership, -> { where(membership: "Standard").order(created_at: :desc) }
```

Comment: if you chain two `where` clauses, as `.where().where()`, they get joined by an AND. Does that help?

Comment: thanks that worked, didn't realize you could chain a .where() to another .where() it worked out good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways you can do this. In the examples below, I have added the condition(AND) `someNum = 1` to the expressions you provided.

You can either add `AND` to the `where` clause ...

```
scope :by_group_title, -> (group) { where('title LIKE ? and someNum = 1',"%#{group}%" ).order(created_at: :desc) if group.present? }
```

Or use the ActiveRecord fields ...

```
scope :by_standard_membership, -> { where(membership: "Standard", someNum: 1).order(created_at: :desc) }
```

Alternatively, you can chain the `where` clauses together ...

```
scope :by_standard_membership, -> { where(membership: "Standard").where(someNum: 1).order(created_at: :desc) }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I ended up chaining the where clauses.  `scope :by_group_title, -> (group) { where('title LIKE ?',"%#{group}%" ).where(membership: "Standard").order(created_at: :desc) if group.present? }`